# Blackberry WebWorks + Ripple, whats the easiest way to distribute app?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-webworks, ripple

Currently I use Ripple "Package and Sign" option, and then use Blackberry Desktop Manager (with my blackberry connected to PC via USB) to import then apply the app. What annoys me is the whole process takes min 10mins sometimes 30mins all up.

I try to skip the "Sign" option, ie use "Package" only but when running the app from the device it gives me this error: "Error starting X: Module 'X' attempts to access a secure API".

Questions:

1. How are you installing the app on blackberry during Dev/Test?
2. How are you distributing the app for PROD release?
3. I have heard we can distribute via Wi-Fi or just sending someone a link to download the app, but cant really find much info on it. Any help?

Comment: May be this link help full. http://keraisureshvblackberry.blogspot.in/2012/04/convert-webapplication-to-blackberry.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sign Webworks apps that you intend to use on the phone. Test as much as you can in the simulator, since it has the fastest turn around time between compiling and running the application.

[Appworld](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/devzone/appworld/) is probably going to be your easiest distribution method if you intend on having users buy your app.

If you want to use the internet/WiFi option, you'll need to have a webserver/site you can upload all the *.cod and *.jad files that are built when you package the app. Then point the people downloading the app to the .jad file and their phone will try to install it for them.

Comment: so, when testing on device do you also use Blackberry Desktop Manager to install the app?

Comment: Yes. And it is frustrating. Sign and package app, uninstall on phone, reboot, install. Gets tedious. I could probably save some restart by incrementing the version number, but I don't like doing that other than real releases.